# DotNotation instead of hardcoded string for culture localization

Tags: c#, .net, localization, api-design

I'm adding the localization in my C# web API server written in .NET6; the user can provide the culture in the URI, therefore I have added these routes in one of my Controller:

```cs
[Route("api/v1/user/")]
[Route("api/v1/{culture:culture}/user/")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
   ...
}
```

Note that I'm using a custom constraint named `culture`.
Then, in my `Program.cs` file I've the following code, which includes the registration of the custom constraint:

```cs
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options => options.ConstraintMap.Add("culture", typeof(CultureRouteConstraint)));
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new string[] { "en-US", "it-IT" };

    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures.First())
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);

    options.RequestCultureProviders = new[] { new RuoteRequestCultureProvider() };
});

...


var options = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
```

Then, I have created a "middle" service to use `IStringLocalizer`, which has been registered in the `Program.cs` file:

```cs
public interface ILocalizer : IStringLocalizer<Resources.Resources>
{
}

public class Localizer : ILocalizer
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<Resources.Resources> _stringLocalizer;

    public Localizer(IStringLocalizer<Resources.Resources> stringLocalizer)
    {
        _stringLocalizer = stringLocalizer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stringLocalizer));
    }

    public LocalizedString this[string name] => _stringLocalizer[name];

    public LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments] => _stringLocalizer[name, arguments];

    public IEnumerable<LocalizedString> GetAllStrings(bool includeParentCultures) => _stringLocalizer.GetAllStrings(includeParentCultures);
}
```

Finally, I have created two separates files, having this structure:

- Resources [Folder]

  - Resources.cs (Empty class)
  - Resources.it-IT.resx
  - Resources.en-US.resx

Just for testing, I have added a single entry in both file, named "Language" with values "English" and "Italiano".

Finally, I have created a simple method in the controller to test the functionality:

```cs
[Route("api/v1/user/")]
[Route("api/v1/{culture:culture}/user/")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILocalizer _localizer;

    public UserController(ILocalizer localizer) => _localizer = localizer;

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ping")]
    public IActionResult Ping()
    {
        return Ok(_localizer.GetString("Language"));
    }
}
```

It works great! The call returns me "English" or "Italiano" correctly. BUT, what I don't like is that `"Language"` string is hard coded, and if  tomorrow I change the string in the resources file, then the code will break.

Usually, when I create an .resx file in Properties folder, I can call it like `Properties.Resources.Language`, which leads to better refactorization in the future.

Therefore, I have two questions:

- Can I obtain the dot notation instead of hard coding the name of the key?
- Can I somehow force the two resx file to have the same exact keys? Probably, I can create a service that runs once when the Web API is running and stop the server right away if it finds missmatch.